# Same ticks in log-plot

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm generating a logplot using the following lines:

```
# Set log-los scale and axes
ax.set_xscale('log')
ax.set_yscale('log')
ax.set_xlabel(r'$x$')
ax.set_ylabel(r'$y$')
ax.set_aspect('equal')
ax.set_xlim([1e-7, 1e0])
ax.set_ylim([1e-7, 1e0])
```

but the result is not what I expected:

[image]

How can I make the x-axis look like the y-axis in terms of ticks? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While it's technically true that `ax.set_adjustable('datalim')` brings back the minor ticks, that's only because it negates the equal axes set in this line:

```
...
ax.set_aspect('equal')
...
```

**The root cause**: `set_aspect('equal')` shrinks the x axis to the point that matplotlib decides to auto-remove the minor ticks.

---

To have both an `equal` aspect ratio *and* minor x ticks, use the [`LogLocator`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/ticker_api.html#matplotlib.ticker.LogLocator) from the [`ticker`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/ticker_api.html) module:

```
from matplotlib.ticker import LogLocator

ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(LogLocator(numticks=10))
ax.xaxis.set_minor_locator(LogLocator(numticks=10, subs=np.arange(0.1, 1, 0.1)))
```

[image]